# how to create a thumbnail image with embedded video code

Tags: php

How to create a thumbnail image with embedded video code. For example i am having the following embedded code:

```
> <object width="480"
> height="385"><param name="movie"
> value="http://www.youtube.com/v/6r-mz0dh6cs&hl=en_US&fs=1&"></param><param
> name="allowFullScreen"
> value="true"></param><param
> name="allowscriptaccess"
> value="always"></param><embed
> src="http://www.youtube.com/v/6r-mz0dh6cs&hl=en_US&fs=1&"
> type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
> allowscriptaccess="always"
> allowfullscreen="true" width="480"
> height="385"></embed></object>
```

The above is  my sample embedded code.

Now i need to display the thumbnail image of this video and while clicking on that thumbnail image the corresponding  video must play.

Now, My Prob is **"HOW TO CREATE A THUMBNAIL IMAGE OF AN EMBEDDED VIDEO CODE"**

thanks in advance

Comment: plz insert your embedded code i dont realy understand what you are trying to do atm.

Answer (score 0):

**NEW ANSWER**

Can now see the code that you are using. You can pull an image of the video straight from Youtube via URL, or use the Youtube API. See this:-

[How do I get a YouTube video thumbnail from the YouTube API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068344/how-to-get-thumbnail-of-youtube-video-link-using-youtube-api)

OLD ANSWER THAT IS IRRELEVANT

Your code isn't there. But I am guessing that you want to create a thumbnail from an uploaded video file.

You can do this using ffmpeg see here: http://blog.prashanthellina.com/2008/03/29/creating-video-thumbnails-using-ffmpeg/

If you want to "flick" through the video on mouseover of the thumbnail, you'll have to grab a load of thumbnails and play them in order using Javascript. You can do some calculations to work out length of the video and calculate the frame interval you want to grab the thumbnail from.